# Powershell Script to download Azure recommendations

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

```
Login-AzAccount

$subs= az account list --query '[*].id'
Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation list --subscription $subs
```

I need to download the list of Azure recommendations on a tenant which will be having multiple subscriptions using Powershell script

Comment: Is the code you have not working? Working but producing unexpected or incomplete results? Please be mindful that we cannot see your screen, so you're gonna have to describe the behavior you're seeing and share any error messages you might observe :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, please find the below error message.
Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '--subscription'.
At line:4 char:1
+ Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation list --subscription $subs
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Advisor.Cmdlets.GetAzAdvisorRecommendation

Comment: @abraradil - please add details in your question, as an edit; formatted text (like PowerShell output) should not be placed in a comment, as it's very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation list --subscription $subs

Instead of **--subscription** you need to pass **-subscription** as a parameter to `Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation` cmdlet.

As per the [Azure PowerShell cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.advisor/get-azadvisorrecommendation?view=azps-7.2.0) documentation, The Cmdlet `Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation` doesnt have any flag  `-subscription` as parameter.

You can use this below script to pull the azure advisor recommendations for all subscriptions under a particular tenant.

```html
$list=@()
$sub=get-azsubscription
Write-Output $sub 
foreach( $item in $sub){

    Set-AzContext -Subscription $item.Id -Tenant $item.TenantId -Force
    $rg=Get-AzResourceGroup
    foreach($r in $rg){
   
        $list+=Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation -ResourceGroupName $r.ResourceGroupName
        }
}
$list | Export-Csv C:\Users\list.csv
```

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

While testing the above script in our local environment, we have passed a single subscription to the cmdlet  `Get-azsubscription` using the `-subscriptionId` flag.

[image]

Comment: I was able to run the script and export the CSV file, but the file is empty, even after specifying the subscription ID the file downloaded is empty.

Comment: Can you try passing the `-subscription` flag (pass a single subscription) & add a statement in the outer for loop `write-output $list` & check whether we are able to get the list of particular subscription advisor recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Using this updated script, I can download the recommendations as well, thanks Venkatesh for your inputs.

```
Login-AzAccount
$result= 'C:\Users\new.csv'
$list=@()
$subs=get-AzSubscription
foreach( $sub in $subs){
Set-AzContext -Subscription $sub.Id -Force
$list+=Get-AzAdvisorRecommendation | Select-Object category, Impact, @{Name="SubscriptionName"; Expression={$sub.name}}, @{Name="SubscriptionID"; 
Expression={$sub.Id}}, @{Name="Recommendation"; Expression=$_.ShortDescription.Problem}}, ImpactedField, ImpactedValue,RecommendationTypeId, LastUpdated, MetaData, SuppressionId, Name, 
resourceid
}
$list | Export-Csv $result -NoTypeInformation
```